# Where do I find code examples of a Drupal client consuming WCF Web Service?

Tags: drupal, wcf-client

I have a WCF Web Service up and running in a production environment, and everything works fine if I use a .NET client. But now I want to test if I have the ability to use this Web Service with a Drupal client.

I've searched for the topic, but didn't find any useful content. If anyone have any leads to get me forward I would greatly appreciate it.

**Where do I find code examples of a Drupal client consuming WCF Web Service?**

Comment: I did a bit of google search and could not find anything . I think you could try the services module / section in drupal for more.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same, but didn't find anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using [wsclient](http://drupal.org/project/wsclient) to consume a SOAP webservice is available [here](http://drupal.org/node/1114308).

Note this example uses a ASMX webservice.

See [here](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com.au/2006/12/how-to-expose-wcf-service-also-as-asmx.html) for how to expose a WCF Web service as an ASMX webservice.

Also see the internal documentation of the following drupal modules

- [soapclient module](http://www.drupal.org/project/soapclient) ,this can use NuSoap internally.

  Also see [Complex Calls With Soap Client](http://www.drupaler.co.uk/blog/complex-calls-soap-client/77).

  There is an example in the comments.
- [clients module](http://www.drupal.org/project/clients),  [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1228830), [readme](http://drupalcode.org/project/clients.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/README.txt)
- Also see the general resources on [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

  - [Introduction to NuSOAP](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapintro.htm)
  - [WSDL and NuSOAP](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapprogwsdl.htm)
  - [Executing a SOAP call from Drupal using nusoap](http://ericlondon.com/executing-soap-call-drupal-using-nusoap)

Comment: Thanx! The NuSOAP seems to be what I'm after. Have you tried the NuSOAP yourself?

Comment: Not recently. From memory I last tried NuSOAP in 2005 and that wasn't a using WCF webservice.

Comment: From what I know you couldn't in 2005, since WCF released in 2006 :) But if NuSOAP have been around for at least 8 years, It can't be all that bad.

Comment: As I said , I was not using a WCF webservice. NuSOAP has been around since 2002.